# What's the default rotate symbol for iOs?

Tags: ios, symbols

What's the default rotate symbol for iOs?

Is it the second icon in this Instagram iPhone app screenshot? It doesn't look like a rotate symbol to me (more like a back or undo button).

[image]

Comment: Yup. That looks like back/undo symbol to me. Here's what Google shows for "rotate icon": http://images.google.com/search?q=rotate+icon

Comment: Thanks dnbrv, I'm looking for the default button that is being used throughout many other iPad apps.

Comment: Does the default photo viewer have the rotation option? (not an iOS user - don't know & can't check)

Answer (score 4):

The button you gave as an example is a default iOS button for rotate since version iOS5 i think. It is used in photo app for the same purpose. (i highlighted it at the bottom on screenshot)

Back to cooking... ;)

[image: rotate icon ios]

Comment: Did you make enough for everyone? ;)